# How to store values of JSON in ARRAY/ String

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have the following JSON value:

```
-(
            { Key   = IsEmail;
              Value = 1;     },

            { Key   = TrackingInterval;
              Value = 20;    },

            { Key   = IsBackup;
              Value = 1;     },

            { Key   = WipeOnRestore;
              Value = 1;     }
)
```

How might I go about parsing this object into an array or string? - i.e. eack **key** values to be stored in an array and each **Value** to be stored in another array.

Please help me out with this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This approach uses the [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/).

I've shortened your example:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"[{\"Key\":\"IsEmail\",\"Value\":\"1\"},{\"Key\":\"TrackingInterval\",\"Value\":\"20\"},{\"Key\":\"IsBackup\",\"Value\":\"1\"}]";

NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];    

NSArray *json = [jsonString JSONValue];

for (NSDictionary *pair in json) {
    [keys addObject:[pair objectForKey:@"Key"]];
    [values addObject:[pair objectForKey:@"Value"]];        
}

NSLog(@"%@", keys); 
NSLog(@"%@", values);
```

Output:

```
2011-05-18 14:23:55.698 [36736:207] (
    IsEmail,
    TrackingInterval,
    IsBackup
)
2011-05-18 14:23:55.700 [36736:207] (
    1,
    20,
    1
)
```

Comment: Why have you used two separate arrays instead of using a dictionary?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer because the OP asked for it: "...eack key values to be stored in an array and each Value to be stored in another array."

Comment: =) Nice. I didn't read the end of his question. That's a very odd way of storing it. Generally it has been my experience that you don't want to store related information in separate objects without a good link between it. In this case the only link is the index, which could get easily screwed up.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer you're absolutely right, but I was in no mood to object so I just coded a direct answer to the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Refere

- http://www.xprogress.com/post-44-how-to-parse-json-files-on-iphone-in-objective-c-into-nsarray-and-nsdictionary/
- http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/
- http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api/
- http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not vald json, You may want to structure it more like this:

```
var theObj = { IsEmail: 1, TrackingInterval: 20, IsBackup: 1, WipeOnRestore: 1 };
```

Then you could populate your key and value arrays something like this:

```
var keys = new Array();
var values = new Array();

for (prop in theObj) {
    keys.push(prop);
    values.push(theObj[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the JSON is in below format,

```
responseString=[ {
        Key = IsEmail;
        Value = 1;
    },
            {
        Key = TrackingInterval;
        Value = 20;
    },
            {
        Key = IsBackup;
        Value = 1;
    },
            {
        Key = WipeOnRestore;
        Value = 1;
    }] 

 then,

NSArray *resultArray=[responseSrting JSONValue];

NSMuatbleArray *keyArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *valueArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSDictionary *dict in resultsArray){

[keyArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"Key"]];

[valueArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"Value"]];

}
```

then, all your keys are stored in keyArray and all your values are stored in valueArray